# Using Immersive Mode for a View

Tags: android

I want to use Immersive mode on a View. not an activity. but the Appropriate Method does nothing! Code:

```
final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN ,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
myView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
        myView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
wm.addView(myView,params); //I have set some params upper
```

to Confirm, I'm using these methods in a BroadcastReceiver and I do not want to start an activity.
After Using the above code, Navigation buttons still show up without any swipe. So my view will not be FullScreen on Kitkat+